# Can I use jQuery nth child to receive the button clicked?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to write my first script (a slideshow).

I would like to have my thumbs clickable to take you to specific slides. Can I use something like nth child to find out which link is being clicked so that I know what slide to move to?

So far I have this:

```
function changeSlide() {

//Get id of link calling
var clicked = $(this).attr("id");

 //Get the current slide and thumb
 var currentSlide = $('ul.slideshow li.show');      
 var currentThumb = $('ul.thumbs li.show'); 

 var nextSlide = $('ul.slideshow').nth-child(clicked);
```

My idea was that I would then use these variables to animate the current slide/thumb out and fade the next slide/thumb in. As I dont know how many slides/thumbs there would be, I would like to be able to select them by their sibling number, does this make sense?

I know its not much, i know just enough to be dangerous.
Any help to keep me going down the right path is appreciated!

======= EDIT ========

I think I may be on to something, would index() be a good match for this?

Here is a link to the script ---> [Slideshow](http://www.getstefan.com/learning/slideshow.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
//Add changeSlide call to anchor tags
$('ul.thumbs li a').attr('onClick', 'changeSlide(' + speed + ')');
```

to

```
//Add changeSlide call to anchor tags
$('ul.thumbs li a').click(function(){
    changeSlide(speed, this);
});
```

and

```
function changeSlide(speed) {

    //Get id of link calling
    var clicked = $(this);
```

to

```
function changeSlide(speed, el) {

    //Get id of link calling
    var clicked = $(el);
```

Comment: ok let me try it, I think you nailed what I was trying to do. Ill get back momentarily.

Comment: Quick question, what is a better programming practice? to add in one of my functions something like: $('ul.thumbs li a').attr('onClick', 'changeSlide()'); so that every anchor tag calls the function... or should I put in the document ready section $('ul.thumbs li a').click(function(){ changeSlide(); });

Comment: `$('ul.thumbs li a').click(function(){ changeSlide(); });` would work wherever it is declared & either works...I always use `.click()`, though. You could also do `$('ul.thumbs li a').click(changeSlide);`

Comment: ok im having problems, i added alert(clicked.index()); to try and debug and its returning "-1" everytime I click...

Comment: i added a link above to the page, it will probably help

Comment: What event handler is calling changeSlide()?

Comment: sorry was at lunch, will look it over now.

Comment: wow, it worked. Awesome stuff thank you. I barely understand what you did, but i am getting there. It seems that now that "speed" is being handed to changeSlide() it is keeping the delay timing, but I cant understand how it knows to do that? Is it just a coincidence?

Comment: hmm spoke too soon, actually it just keeps taking me back to the first slide.

Comment: i think i found it, were getting the index for the <A> tag when actually I want the index for the parent("li")

Comment: yep it appears to go to the right slide/thumb now, only thing is its set to rotate every 4 seconds, if i click a new slide at say second 2, the next slide only stays up for 2 seconds rather than 4. Any idea how I can reset that timer on click?

Comment: Nevermind, I think i got it, Ill just keep plugging away. Youve been a huge help thank you very much!